# Why does it call the "wrong" equal method?

Tags: ruby, equality

Last week I wanted to answer a question here on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/), but after running some tests in **irb** I've found an interesting thing.

```
class X
  def ==(other)
    p "X#=="
    super
  end
end

data = [ 1 ]
data.include?(X.new)
```

I expect here that `Array#include?` will call `Fixnum#==` on every item in the array. So the `X#==` is never get called and the debug message never gets printed.

But actually in my ruby versions (REE 1.8.7, MRI 1.8.7, 1.9.2 and 1.9.3) it prints out the `X#==` debug message.

If I do that on `true` or `false` or `nil` or even `Object.new` it never prints out the `X#==` message.

But if I redefine the `Fixnum#==` like this:

```
class Fixnum
  def ==(other)
    p "Fixnum#=="
    super
  end
end
```

Which actually calls the original implementation after printing a debug message, it prints out `Fixnum#==` and `X#==` never gets printed out as I expected originally.

#### Update

It gets even crazier, when I switch the haystack with the needle:

```
data = [ X.new ]
data.include?(1)
```

It prints out `X#==` even though it called the `#==` method on the needle before.

Could anybody point out what is the reason behind that? Or simply an optimization issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So `include?` will send `:==` to each element of your array.

If your elements are `true`, `false`, and `nil`, the equality test fails readily because only `true` is `==` to `true`, etc...

For `Fixnum`s, it's not that clear, for example `1 == 1.0 # => true`. So `Fixnum#==` will be polite in case of an unknown argument and reverse the order of the arguments. This would allow you to define your own "numerical" types.

Now what confused you even more, is that in order to understand what's going on, you **redefined** `Fixnum#==`. Calling `super` won't call the original method but `Object#==` instead. Try `alias_method_chain` (or `prepend` if in Ruby 2.0!)

BTW, looking at the actual source, `Fixnum` will deal directly with `Fixnum`, `Bignum` and `Float`. For other builtin classes (e.g. `Rational`, `Complex`, `BigDecimal`) as well as user classes, `Fixnum#==` will reverse the receiver and the argument. I wouldn't rely on the fact that it does this for `Rational`, but all implementations will do this for user classes.

Comment: Did you read the first part of the question? I expect to call `Fixnum#==` but it calls my implementation first.

Comment: @KARASZIIstván: I'm so sorry, I completely misread your question. Answer fixed :-)

Comment: And now answers my question with the "polite" part :)

Comment: Actually it answers. I need to do the debug with `alias_method` instead of overwriting.

Comment: Is there a badge for having the same answer accepted like 4 times? ;-)

Comment: I accepted only twice as far as I remember, but there should be :)

Comment: Curiously, this "polite reversed-order ==" behavior slighly varies by type.  For example [`"string".==(other)`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/4e44f6ef8668faa59898de2da7612b6a2cad1eb8/string.c#L3038-L3064) tries `other.===("string")` only if `other.respond_to? :to_str`, i.e. for objects that advertise they ["act like a string"](https://gist.github.com/kinopyo/5682347).